# Unable to resolve specifier 'popper' imported from | Dropdown of bootstrap in Rails 7 with importmap doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use the dropdown function of bootstrap with importmap and already pinned both boostrap and popper but it does not work

My application.js is as follows:

```
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "controllers"
import "bootstrap"
import "popper"
import "@popperjs/core"
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free"
```

config/importmap.rb

```
pin "application", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "turbo.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js", preload: true
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"
pin "bootstrap", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.esm.js"
pin "@popperjs/core", to: "https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/esm/index.js"
pin "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.2.0/js/all.js"
```

This happened when I clicked the link showed in the console

```
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "controllers"
import "bootstrap"
import "popper";
```

This showed in my console

Uncaught Error: Unable to resolve specifier 'popper' imported from http://127.0.0.1:3000/assets/application-8b4b95736718a0fcee6267f7d3b80537828999e5cbd5f3a04eaacbed2ab415bf.js

Also, my fontawesome doesn't work as well

Comment: Just note that my head for html is as follows:   <head>
    <title>Clone2ch</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
    <%= javascript_importmap_tags %>
  </head>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found that I used the wrong bootstrap version (I installed 5 but used the 4 version template) Importmap works!!

Comment: The version of bootstrap was the issue. Need to mactch version of popperjs in importmap.rb and bootstrap template.

Answer (score 2):

Popper.js assumes you have WebPack or another build tool to process the environment variables and check for whether you are running in `production` or another environment.

This is what your `app/javascript/application.js` needs to look like:

```js
import '@hotwired/turbo-rails'
window.process = { env: { NODE_ENV: 'production' } };
import '@popperjs/core'
import 'bootstrap'
import 'controllers'
```

This is based on the Github issue here: https://github.com/floating-ui/floating-ui/issues/933#issuecomment-581745991

Comment: it's enough:
`window.process = { env: {} }`
as explained in https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails/issues/65

Answer (score 1):

I also have an issue the same to you.

I fixed and push my git. You can watch my way.

> https://github.com/linh236/bootstrap_rails

Comment: Appreciate your answer and will look into it sir!

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure if the way you used in the link is using esbuild together with importmap?

Comment: At here, i use gem `bundle add jsbundling-rails`, `./bin/rails javascript:install:esbuild`. Next, , i use `yarn` add to the lib `bootstrap, bootstrap-icons ...`

Comment: Thank you sir but I believe that is not the correct way to solve this issue since esbuild will smoosh the importmap function

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue following step-by-step [this tutorial](https://jasonfleetwoodboldt.com/courses/rails-7-crash-course/rails-7-importmap-rails-with-bootstrap-stimulus-turbo-long-tutorial/), for some reason running `/bin/importmap pin @popperjs/core@2.11.2` results with `pin "@popperjs/core", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@popperjs/core@2.11.2/lib/index.js"` in the `config/importmap` which caused a `Uncaught TypeError: t.createPopper is not a function rails` error. Instead you want to use `pin "@popperjs/core", to: "https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/esm/index.js"` - this resolved my issue. I hope it's helpful

Comment: this article solved it for me, I had `pin "@popperjs/core", to: "popper.js", preload: true` in `importmap.rb` but had to change it to `pin "popper", to: "popper.js", preload: true`